# MySQL's comment /*!50100 */ didn't work in Version 5.7

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, sql-comments

I have try to create full text index.

I use the "  FULLTEXT KEY book_name (book_name) WITH PARSER ngram ".

After created the table , the "show create table " shows that the upper line turned to be "  FULLTEXT KEY book_name (book_name) /*!50100 WITH PARSER `ngram` */"

But It didn't work really. I can't use the full text search.

I put the source code here : [db fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/du9TETDrUzQJTFumgFZour/4)

You can see the difference. I don't know why.

Comment: Have you tested this on your own database? Testing this on e.g. [dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/iZQcZsuq) seems to behave as expected, so maybe [db-fiddle.com](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/du9TETDrUzQJTFumgFZour/4) just ignores any kind of comment.

Answer (score 0):

Why are You using MYISAM as engine , use INNODB

```
CREATE TABLE tmp1 (
  book_name char(32) NOT NULL,
  FULLTEXT KEY book_name (book_name) /*!50100 WITH PARSER `ngram` */
) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

So at least the FULL TEXT works fine with english text, but if it works with asian text i don't know

Comment: I am using a old table which I can't modify it to INNODB, so I want to fix this problem using MyISAM

Comment: There is no fix for it, it os a bug but myisam is old, you can write a bug report

Answer (score 0):

Is this relevant?

---- 2018-07-27 8.0.12 General Availability & 2018-07-27 5.7.23 General Availability -- -- InnoDB -----

The ngram full-text search parser permitted comma and period characters to be tokenized as words, which caused an inconsistency between boolean and natural language mode search results. Comma and period characters are no longer tokenized. (Bug #27847697)